# command not found in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am running a shell script on my server. Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#----- cd /change working directory
cd /Net/Groups/BGI/people/sbesnard/PhD_MPI/RO1/Rproject/Landsat_Processing/Scripts/
ulimit -c 0
#----- specify the R-Script, commandline argument $1 has precedence

# get the error messages in english
export LANG=en_US
# only one thread, no automatic distributed computing
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

export BGC=PGI

RFILE=1.TC_Component_Calculation.R
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  RFILE=$1
fi
#echo $RFILE
#echo Rout/`basename $RFILE .R`.rout
echo $RFILE
DATUM=$(date '+%d_%m_%Y_%Hh%Mm') 

FOLDER="${DATUM}_${LSB_JOBNAME}"
NUMPROC="$LSB_MCPU_HOSTS"

echo $DATUM

mkdir /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/sbesnard/Rout/Rout_TC_Calc/$FOLDER 

#--------- execute R
/usr/local/apps/R/R-3.2.2/bin/R CMD BATCH  --vanilla "--args $FOLDER $NUMPROC" $RFILE /Net/Groups/BGI/scratch/sbesnard/Rout/Rout_TC_Calc/$FOLDER/${LSB_JOBNAME}.rout
```

However, I have this error message but have no idea on how to fix it.

```
/User/homes/sbesnard/.lsbatch/1476445696.215609: line 8: bsub_TC_calc.sh: command not found
```

Any idea from where the error is coming from?

Comment: Replace `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash -x` and rerun.  That will highlight where the error is coming from.

Comment: You mean if I do a simple sh file.sh ?

Comment: No, edit the script, change the first line to have `-x`, that means more debug info is output.

Comment: Ok but I do not see any more information when I run the .sh file.

Comment: nothing in your posted example calls bsub_TC_calc.sh,so the first step is to find where that's coming in. I'm also not sure where the `/User/homes/sbesnard/.lsbatch/1476445696.215609` path is coming from; is that the (oddly-named) name of your script?